# Xcode testcase : difference in time displayed in log and system time

Tags: ios, time, testcase, xcode6.4

I'm running test-case on Xcode 6.4. The `log for test-case shows different time as compared to time displayed in Mac System`. I'm running on *Indian Standard Time (IST)*. Why is this difference?

[image: Screenshot-1-log-time]

[image: Screenshot-2-System-time]

Comment: Good attention to detail!

Answer (score 0):

Your system time show by adding about +5.5 hours with GMT time.

Comment: I'm running test-case on my local system and hence both time should be same.

Comment: but time is not local. your system show GMT(Greenwich Mean Time) time and device shows local time adjusting from GMT time.